# Issue running sencha application on mobile as a native app

Tags: cordova, extjs, extjs6, sencha-cmd

I see nothing when i load my application in android device even after the native build works fine

Steps I used:

1. Run sencha production build //works fine
2. Check the application in production env //works fine
3. initialize the application with cordova for first time //works fine
4. Once cordova project is created
5. Add build additional build profile for android to my app.json with following

   "android": {
           "toolkit": "modern",
           "theme": "theme-triton",
           "packager": "cordova",
           "cordova": {
               "config": {
                   "platforms": "android",
                   "id": "com.mydomain.MyApp"
               }
           }
       }
6. sencha app build android  // works fine
7. Fetch the apk generated in outputs/apk folder
8. Launch it in my mobile //Nothing shows
9. I connect with chrome dev tools and check for the web view inside application //?Not sure if right way to go about it
10. [I see following error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8ipc.png)

Everything looks fine until generation of apk… 
Installation of apk in phone also works properly

Application loading is showing the above mentioned error.
Any help will be very much appreciated

Comment: You can open an APK file using a ZIP tool like 7zip. You can then navigate the folder structure, search for your index.html and check whether the file modern.jsonp is available next to it, or extract the whole folder to check what's going on.

Comment: @Alexander , thanks for the tip.. here i checked the files present in production build with files present in developer build... both look similar except modern.json and moder.jsonp is replace by android.json and android.jsonp ...

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Which version of Cmd do you use?

Comment: Sencha v6.2.1.29

Comment: I had many issues with Sencha Cmd's cordova build at first, and when I was fed up, I made my own shellscript that first calls `sencha app build production`, then copies the files over into the cordova folder and then calls `cordova build android -release` independently. Saved me tons of time figuring out what went wrong in Sencha Cmd.

Comment: Thanks @Alexander! I did the workaround as u suggested.. saved my lots of time as well!